# How to properly instantiate a Thrift/Scrooge generated class in Scala

Tags: scala, wrapper, thrift, scrooge

I would like to instantiate a crooge generated class (or trait, better said).
Now since I can't instantiate a trait, I used a anonymous wrapper class to generate some test object I want to serealize:

```
val err = new ClientError{}
```

But I cannot set any properties to this object (or at least I don't know how).
What's the proper way to do this?
The background is I want to create an object, serialize it, send it, deserialize it and check if it worked, if the sample has the same properties.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an *object* `ClientError`, with an `apply` method.
Just do

```
val err = ClientError(whatever, fields, your, thrift, struct, has)
```

Comment: If I do, I get "trait ClientError is abstract, cannot be instantiated".

Comment: I must be doing `new ClientError(...)` try it without `new`